# Build php 7 using libressl

Tags: php, linux, build, alpine-linux, libressl

In Alpine 3.5 the default is LibreSSL. How can I compile php 7.0.xx using libressl instead of openssl?

P.S. I know that you can install OpenSSL, but I still need curl-dev and postgresql-dev where LibreSSL is required, and a shared installation is not possible. You can compile these packages with LibreSSL support, or use alpine 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sent response on another site. Updated the version of php from 7.0.18 to 7.0.19, and instead of --with-openssl pointed out --with-openssl = / usr and the problem was solved. Prior to this, an error occurred during the build: OpenSSL> = 1.1.0

[Docker Alpine-php](https://github.com/AlexMasterov/dockerfiles/tree/master/alpine-php)